# Selecting specific values in List depending on control values in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have a list of String and it has values like {"val1, "val2", "val3", "val4"}
and i have three different combo boxes. Each combo box has more than 5 items.

Now I want to select only one value from the list with different combinations of the combo box items. I have tried it using if-else and switch statement but its really tedious process. So what is the best approach to solve this kind of problem? 
screenshot of the part of the GUI.

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LunCr.png)

Thanks in advance.

and i have a long nested switch-case like this

```
 switch(comboBox1_value)
   {
            case "X1" :
                switch(comboBox2_value)
                {
                case "X1":
                    // select val1 from list
                    break;
                case "X2":
                    // select val2 from list
                    break;

                case "K1":
                    // select val3 from list
                    break;
                case "K2":
                    // select val1 from list
                    break;
                }
           .
           .
           .
    }
```

Comment: What is a combo box here ? Can you give example and your code ?

Comment: its a long switch case statement with more than 400 lines of code. Should i post it?

Comment: I have attached screenshot of part of my GUI and added a code that should clear the concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    private static String[] X_VALUES = {"x1","x2","x3","x3",};
    private static String[] Y_VALUES = {"y1","y2","y3","y3",};
    private static String[] Z_VALUES = {"z1","z2","z3","z3",};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JComboBox<String> x_c = new JComboBox<>(X_VALUES);
        JComboBox<String> y_c = new JComboBox<>(Y_VALUES);
        JComboBox<String> z_c = new JComboBox<>(Z_VALUES);

        java.util.List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

        Stream.of(X_VALUES)
                .forEach(x -> {
                    Stream.of(Y_VALUES)
                    .forEach(y -> {
                        Stream.of(Z_VALUES)
                        .forEach(z -> {
                            l.add("X:" + x + ", Y: " + y + ", Z: " + z);
                        });
                    });
                });

        JList<String> list = new JList<>(l.toArray(new String[l.size()]));

        ActionListener al = e -> { list.setSelectedValue("X:" + x_c.getSelectedItem() + ", Y: " + y_c.getSelectedItem() + ", Z: " + z_c.getSelectedItem(), true); };

        x_c.addActionListener(al);
        y_c.addActionListener(al);
        z_c.addActionListener(al);

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(x_c);
        p.add(y_c);
        p.add(z_c);
        p.add(new JScrollPane(list));

        f.setContentPane(p);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```